# Capture selected value from list using webdriver and Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm using selenium webdriver with ruby.  I've written a script that will fill in a form.  One field is a dropdown list.  What I would like to do is capture the value I selected in the list.

For example:  If I had a list of cars and I selected Honda  I would like to capture the value in the field (Honda) and place it in a variable for me to use later.

I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: You will make more sense if you paste some relevant code and also explain your attempts to solve the problem so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code select list items:

```
cars_select = driver.find_element(:id=> "cars_list")
```

> //use id of your dropdownlist

```
options = cars_select.find_elements(:tag_name=>"option")
options.each do |el|
    if (el.value == "Honda") 
        el.select()
        var selected_car = el.value;
        break
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting from dropdown with:

```
browser.select_list(id: 'some_id').option(text: 'some_value').select
```

Then you can store that value in a variable, like below:

```
var1=browser.select_list(id: 'some_id').option(text: 'some_value').value
```

Hope this will work. If not, then provide your dropdown part html, and explain more. I am using watir-webdriver, try if this work for selenium-webdriver.